# Override Vimeo default CSS on the player

Tags: html, css, vimeo

[image]

I am trying to access this highlighted div that comes along when a vimeo iframe source is detected. I was wondering if it's even possible to target this and if it even exists in the dom?

Comment: Try adding a `MutationObserver`  to the document and check if it exists when it observed

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that you can. While semantically it looks like the div is loaded inside your page the styling and everything is controlled through vimeo. So the only way you would be able to style it would be if you had access to vimeo's css. There may be options though that allow you to change the theme of the embed or hide certain things.

https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/224972808-Customize-the-video-player